# Magento2.2.5 - Amazon Seller channel Module error

Tags: magento2, module, amazon

We have a magento 2.2.5 based website and just tried installing the Amazon Sales Channel module (https://marketplace.magento.com/magento-module-amazon.html) however after installing it and running the Magento upgrade, compile and deploy command when we then go to login to our Magento admin and are presented with the below error.

I don't understand why I would have to downgrade our other Amazon modules in order to use this nor do I want to downgrade because I am concerned it will cause issues with other stuff on the site if I do.

Has anyone had this issue and if so any work around to getting it to work?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please 
upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Amazon_Core schema: current version - 2.2.10, required version - 2.2.7
Amazon_Core data: current version - 2.2.10, required version - 2.2.7
Amazon_Login schema: current version - 2.2.10, required version - 2.2.7
Amazon_Login data: current version - 2.2.10, required version - 2.2.7
Amazon_Payment schema: current version - 2.2.10, required version - 2.2.7
Amazon_Payment data: current version - 2.2.10, required version - 2.2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this thread it may help: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18248

Comment: That post is slightly different because the person has an older version of the Amazon modules and the error they are getting says they need a newer version. I have the opposite. My existing Amazon modules are newer and what the Amazon Seller Channel module seems to require according to the error message.